# Segmentation fault while iterating through and erasing some elements from std::map?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap

I am using several `std::map` type data containers which are the following:

```
    std::map<int, std::vector< cv::Point > > mapGoodContours;
    std::map<int, EllipseProperties> ellipsePropertiesMap;
    std::map<int, float> m_markerRadiusMap;
    std::map<int,cv::Point2f> markers;//This is part of another class
```

I iterate through these containers and erase some elements after those elements meet certain condition as shown in the following code.

```
    auto radiusMapCounter = m_markerRadiusMap.begin();
    auto markerCounter = frames.markers.begin();
    auto goodContoursCounter = mapGoodContours.begin();

    if(m_markerRadiusMap.size()==ellipsePropertiesMap.size() && frames.markers.size()==ellipsePropertiesMap.size()
            && mapGoodContours.size()==ellipsePropertiesMap.size())
    {
        for(auto ellipsePropertyCounter = ellipsePropertiesMap.begin(); ellipsePropertyCounter != ellipsePropertiesMap.end(); ellipsePropertyCounter++)
        {

            float upperLimit = (float)m_upperFactor*(float)ellipsePropertyCounter->second.radius;
            float lowerLimit = (float)m_lowerFactor*(float)ellipsePropertyCounter->second.radius;
            if(ellipsePropertyCounter->second.minDistanceFromOtherEllipse>upperLimit
                        || ellipsePropertyCounter->second.minDistanceFromOtherEllipse<lowerLimit)
            {
                 ellipsePropertiesMap.erase(ellipsePropertyCounter);
                 m_markerRadiusMap.erase(radiusMapCounter);
                 frames.markers.erase(markerCounter);
                 mapGoodContours.erase(goodContoursCounter);
            }
            else
            {
                 smallContours.push_back(goodContoursCounter->second);
            }

            radiusMapCounter++;
            markerCounter++;
            goodContoursCounter++;
        }
    }
```

I am baffled to find that sometimes I have segmentation faults as shown in the image. [image] The fault specifically points to the line with the code `radiusMapCounter++;`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterator invalidation rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot increment iterator after you erased the element it points to from container. Create a copy of iterator, increment it, delete element via copy.

If you are using C++11 or later, `std::map::erase(...)` returns the iterator following the last removed element, so you can use it instead of incrementing invalid one. No need to create a copy of iterator to use in `erase` in this case.

```
for(auto ellipsePropertyCounter = ellipsePropertiesMap.begin();
    ellipsePropertyCounter != ellipsePropertiesMap.end();
    /* do not increment iterator here */)
{

    float upperLimit = (float)m_upperFactor*(float)ellipsePropertyCounter->second.radius;
    float lowerLimit = (float)m_lowerFactor*(float)ellipsePropertyCounter->second.radius;
    if(ellipsePropertyCounter->second.minDistanceFromOtherEllipse>upperLimit
                || ellipsePropertyCounter->second.minDistanceFromOtherEllipse<lowerLimit)
    {
         ellipsePropertyCounter = ellipsePropertiesMap.erase(ellipsePropertyCounter);
         radiusMapCounter = m_markerRadiusMap.erase(radiusMapCounter);
         markerCounter = frames.markers.erase(markerCounter);
         goodContoursCounter = mapGoodContours.erase(goodContoursCounter);
    }
    else
    {
         smallContours.push_back(goodContoursCounter->second);

         radiusMapCounter++;
         markerCounter++;
         goodContoursCounter++;
         ellipsePropertyCounter++; // increment loop iterator only in 'else' case
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C++17 solution.

First `indexer`, which is C++14 and lets you create and unpack index packs inline without special purpose helpers at point of use:

```
template<class=void,std::size_t...Is>
void indexer( std::index_sequence<Is>... ) {
  return [](auto&& f) {
    using discard=int[];
    (void)discard{0,((
      f( std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>{} )
    ),void(),0)...};
  };
}
template<std::size_t N>
void indexer() {
  return indexer( std::make_index_sequence<N>{} );
}
```

Now, `erase_if`, which should be SFINAE restricted to only work on associative (and maybe other node-based) containers:

```
template<class Test, class...Maps>
bool erase_if( Test&& test, Maps&&...maps) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  std::tuple< decltype(begin(maps))... > its;
  std::tuple< decltype(begin(maps))... > ends;
  auto m_tup = std::tie(maps...);
  auto index = indexer<sizeof...(maps)>;
  index(
    [&](auto i){
      std::get<i>(its) = begin( std::get<i>(m_tup) );
      std::get<i>(ends) = end( std::get<i>(m_tup) );
    }
  );
  while (its != ends) {
    auto deref_then_test = [&test](auto...its) {
      return test( (*its)... );
    };
    if (std::apply(deref_then_test,its)) {
      index(
        [&](auto i){
          std::get<i>(its) = std::get<i>(m_tup).erase(std::get<i>(its));
        }
      );
    } else {
      index(
        [&](auto i){++std::get<i>(its);}
      );
    }
  }
}
```

this lets you erase from multiple containers based off tests on one of them.

Code not tested, probably contians typos.